# What is the white sauce of Domino's pasta made of?

Tags: sauce, pasta, restaurant-mimicry

What is that made of? Can it be replicated at home?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [Alfredo sauce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fettuccine_Alfredo#Alfredo_sauce) and according to [Domino's nutrition guide](http://cache.dominos.com/homev8/docs/menu/dominos_nutrition_v2.21.00.pdf) it's made of:

> **Water**
>   **Cream** *(Cream, Milk)*
>   **Parmesan Cheese** *(Part-Skim Milk, Cheese Cultures, Salt, Enzymes)*
>   **Asiago Cheese** *(Pasteurized
>   Milk, Cheese Culture, Salt, Enzymes)*
>   **Margarine** *(Palm Oil, Water, Salt, Vegetable Monoglycerides, Whey Solids,
> Sodium
>   Benzoate [Preservative], Natural And Artificial Flavor, Citric Acid, Beta Carotene [Color], Vitamin A Palmitate Added)*
>   **Seasoning**
>   *(Maltodextrin, Nonfat Milk, Modified Corn Starch, Salt, Enriched Bleached Wheat Flour [Bleached Wheat Flour, Malted Barley
>   Flour, Niacin, Reduced Iron, Thiamine Mononitrate, Riboflavin, Folic Acid], Disodium Inosinate, Disodium Guanylate, Xanthan
>   Gum, Spices, Mono And Diglycerides)*
>   **Butter** *(Butter, Salt)*
>   **Parmesan Cheese Concentrate** *(Parmesan Cheese [Pasteurized
>   Milk, Cultures, Salt, Enzymes], Water, Salt, Natural Flavors, Yeast Extract, Sodium Phosphates, Sodium Citrate)*
>   **Modified Corn Starch**
>   **Garlic** *(Garlic, Water)*
>   **Chicken Base** *(Chicken Meat, Chicken Juices, Salt, Potato Flour, Flavorings, Sugar, Disodium
>   Inosinate, Disodium Guanylate)*
>   **Parsley**
>   **Salt**

You can definitely make something similar at home. You should also be able to buy something like it in a jar at your local grocery store.

Comment: The *Maltodextrin, Nonfat Milk, Modified Corn Starch, Xanthan Gum and Mono and Diglycerides* are for thickening and stabilizing what would otherwise be a watery mess with melted margarine floating atop. You can use thickening agents available from your supermarket instead. The *Disodium Inosinate+Disodium Guanylate* combo is to enhance the umami flavor of the Parmesan and chicken (and to my cynical mind, in order to avoid putting MSG in the ingredient list). You can probably ignore these taste enhancers if the cheeses and chicken stock provide enough flavor, otherwise you may need to add MSG.